# Transforming a non-linear system of differential equation by variable substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show that the non-linear system $$ x_1'=\alpha_1x_1(\beta_1-x_1)+\gamma_1x_1x_2 \\ x_2'=\alpha_2x_2(\beta_2-x_2)-\gamma_2x_1x_2$$ transforms into $$y_1'=y_1(1-y_1)+a_1y_1y_2 \\ y_2'=y_2(1-y_2)-a_2y_1y_2$$ by means of the substitution $$\beta_1y_1(t)=x_1\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)$$ $$\beta_2y_2(t)=x_2\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_2\beta_2}\right)$$ where $a_1=\frac{\gamma_1\beta_2}{\alpha_1 \beta_1},a_2=\frac{\gamma_2\beta_1}{\alpha_2\beta_2}$.

Here is how I proceeded.

Differentiating both sides of $\beta_1y_1(t)=x_1\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)$ with respect to $t$, we get $$\begin{eqnarray*}\beta_1y_1'(t)&=&\frac{1}{\alpha_1\beta_1}x_1'\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right) \\ &=& \frac{1}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\cdot \Big[\alpha_1x_1\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)\left(\beta_1-x_1\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)\right)+\gamma_1x_1\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)x_2\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)\Big] \\ &=& \frac{1}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\cdot \Big[\alpha_1\beta_1y_1(t)\Big(\beta_1-\beta_1y_1(t)\Big)+\gamma_1\beta_1y_1(t)x_2\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)\Big].\end{eqnarray*}$$ This means $$y_1'(t)=y_1(t)(1-y_1(t))+\tfrac{\gamma_1}{\alpha_1\beta_1}y_1(t)x_2\left(\tfrac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right).$$ Since $x_2\left(\frac{t}{\alpha_1\beta_1}\right)=\beta_2 y_2\left(\tfrac{\alpha_2\beta_2}{\alpha_1\beta_1}t\right)$, we may say $$y_1'(t)=y_1(t)(1-y_1(t))+\tfrac{\gamma_1\beta_2}{\alpha_1\beta_1}y_1(t) y_2\left(\tfrac{\alpha_2\beta_2}{\alpha_1\beta_1}t\right).$$ I was expecting $$y_1'(t)=y_1(t)(1-y_1(t))+\tfrac{\gamma_1\beta_2}{\alpha_1\beta_1}y_1(t) y_2(t).$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. I genuinely believe the problem you've discovered is a real problem. This substitution doesn't work.